# Why can't Control Winds counter a breath weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Related; [Can Warding Wind block the effect of a Green Dragon's Poison Breath?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104768/can-warding-wind-block-the-effect-of-a-green-dragons-poison-breath)

Could you cast Control Winds and direct it to be a gust towards say a dragon and counter the breath weapon? I find it hard that think that in the face of winds strong enough to cut one's movement in half that an exhaled attacks wouldn't just get blown back at the attacker.

The difference is that control winds is constant turbulence of wind as opposed to warding wind's simply circling the caster. This is a difference of a small barrier trying to counter a breathe weapon versus a constant force pushing in the opposite direction.

Am I missing something about the breath weapon? Does magic simply hold a red dragon's flames in that 15 foot cone in spite of the gale blowing in the opposite direction?

Counter to the answer given;
We are talking about gale force winds countering a directional breath attack. Which consist of; fire, lightning, acid, poison gas, and cold AIR! The only one I can logically see not being effected too much by strong opposing winds is the lightning. Everything else by common sense should be pushed aside by winds traveling over 40mph/60kpm. So I ask, does the spell description lacking stating such bypass common sense?

Comment: I don't see how this isn't a duplicate. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: It IS about a different spell, but it has the same answer.

Comment: @daze413 Warding wind and control wind function very differently fundamentally. WW is a simple barrier of wind while CW is a gale that can be directed in a single direction that occupies a 100ft cube of space, the sheer scale of difference should make a difference.

Comment: This question sounds like you've already an answer in mind. Consider excising from the question your opinion about what constitutes a common sense interpretation of the spell so that that opinion can be included in your own self-answering to this question when this question's reopened. (Also, I liked the previous title. I mean, don't *you* find negative questions difficult to answer? I do… or don't… or something.)

Comment: While the questions are asking about different spells, the difference is what philosophy calls a "distinction without difference" for the purpose of dragon breath weapons: they work the same, for the same reasons.

Comment: The broader answer givven there (Pay heed to the spell text) still works for this one.

Comment: Also might be worth noting the type of breath weapon, obviously lightning and fire-laser type breaths don't count, here.

Answer (score 1):

### No.

Again, the wording of the spell must state that it **blocks gases** to be effecttive against the Green Dragon Breath (or any gas spell/effect/breath that does not have a "dispersed by" text).

Control winds has no such text.

Comment: I feel you are dismissing common sense here... How would 40mph winds not disperse such things?

Comment: @Clarus_Nox "common sense" has no power here. This is **magic** - IF you are the DM and want to play as such, nothing is stopping you. But here we take the rules at heart value, unless told otherwise. Common sense would not have flying dragons, or six limbed creatures to begin with.

Comment: @Mindwin Yup.  What kind of world would have [giant flying predators](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/landbeforetime/images/1/13/Quetzalcoatlus.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160328172458) or [six-limbed beings](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/1580533/A-hexapus-not-a-six-legged-octopus.html)?

Comment: @thedarkwanderer forgive my biological innacuracy. i meant six limbed bony creatures.